# Gwt - Unable to load module entry point class

Tags: java, gwt, jar, drag-and-drop, entry-point

I've included the dnd jar in my gwt project(on the build path and on the class path) and when I execute the program the following exception occur.
And I've also included the following line in the module : 
`<inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd' />`

```
 Unable to load module entry point class com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client.util.DragEntryPoint

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/EntryPoint
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1070)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:414)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1192)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.loadClassFromSourceName(ModuleSpace.java:670)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:378)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`
I would like to understand why this error occur when a jar file is added to the project.
For information i'm using the jdk 1.7

Comment: Looks like `gwt-servlet.jar` is missing in your classpath.

Comment: I've looked in WEB-INF/lib and `gwt-servlet.jar` is there.

Comment: com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client.util.DragEntryPoint is in jar right?

Comment: Yes it's inside the jar.

Comment: its jar which will contain the created component(dnd-gwt)..inherit this in your project,use this widget in your project instead of pointing to the jars entry point..

Comment: Can you post your `*.gwt.xml`?

Comment: Here is the module                                                                                   `<module rename-to="Sample">
 <inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd' />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
 <source path="client" />
 <entry-point class="com.sample.gwt.client.Home"></entry-point>
</module>`

Comment: put this  <inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd' /> after <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" /> tag

Comment: I did it, nothing changed same error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem came from  the app engine, I have disabled app engine on the run configuration and put the jar in the user entries instead of the putting it in the bootstrap entries, And everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by **faulty plugin installation** in the Browser you are using. To overcome this use Use GWT(Super Dev Mode) to run the module. It will not show **Entry point class** error.